# MS Teams App with messaging-extensions example

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I came across very good document on [Develop messaging extensions for Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions)

I have all the pieces except How to add code in bot for messaging-extension controller or I guess I would say how to make it work with the Bot built using Nodejs Bot builder SDK 3

Answer (score 1):

These repos have samples of implementing a messaging extension using the Node Teams extension SDK:

- https://github.com/aosolis/bing-msteams (gets articles from Bing News)
- https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/master/src/Bot.ts (fake data source)

Comment: Looks like these are typescript. We you have nodejs once ?

Comment: This (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview) has a good explanation on how to integrate extensions into a bot:

Comment: @RoyJ No sample in pure ES6. Typescript and ES6 are very similar-- you should be able to read the sample and map the concepts to your code.

Comment: @RoyJ - Here is the javascript sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/blob/master/Node/samples/app.js